# How do i add a new individual member?

Tags: civimember, joomla

My colleague is adding new members who have an individual membership type. We use civiCRM through Joomla. The "individual" setting is not saving.  She is doing it through the "Create New" button.  Should she be creating a new member through the "membership" button?

Comment: What do you mean the 'individual' setting is not saving? Is the membership not saving or are you having issues selecting that membership type when on the Contact's membership tab and have selected Add New Membership?

Comment: It's not clear from the information you've given in your question as to what is actually happening here. More detail would be really helpful.

Comment: I did have an issue on a site recently where the basic search resulted in both individuals and organisations despite selecting the 'Individual' contact type as a search filter. Upgrading to the current version solved that problem. I don't know if this is relevant?